# How can I filter multiple key fields in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to filter my set of documents from mongo. I have keys in my document that share common suffix of _flag and the rest can be anything. This keys are flagged to Boolean values.

I just need to filter only for false value.
I could filter the false values by providing the full name of the key itself. But I need to filter all documents that have the key suffix extension of _flag.

I am attaching my document below :

```
{
  "id":1,
  "rollno":"212",
  "StudentName":"Ammi",
  "details":{
    "examNo":2,
    "form":[
      [
        {
          "F_id":"443",
          "text":"First Name",
          "type":"text",
          "required":true,
          "School":{
            "key":"First_Name",
            "label":"First Name"
          },
          "First_Name_flag":false
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "F_id":"444",
          "text":"Second Name",
          "type":"text",
          "required":true,
          "School":{
            "key":"Second_Name",
            "label":"Second Name"
          },
          "Second_Name_flag":false
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "Admitted":true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Evaldas Buinauskas

Comment: You might have to resort to [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce) for this task, otherwise change your schema to use embedded documents with (key/value) pairs e.g `[{ key: "First_Name_flag": value: false }, { key: "Second_Name_flag": value: false }]`

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific around how exactly you would want to filter and what exactly you'd want to get as a result? An example would help a lot...